# delete all folders/directories with a common prefix name - python

Tags: python, directory, delete-file, prefix

I would like to delete all folders/directories with a common prefix name.
How can this be achieved in python ?

example :
all folders with names with prefix - 'reports_'

Comment: All folders, but don't delete any files? Have you take a looked [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree), [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) and [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)? What have you done already?

Comment: Or use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) instead of `os.listdir` and `str.startswith`.

Answer (score 5):

this is the simplest solution that I could think of to solve your problem.

```
import shutil
import glob
import os
base_path = ""
dir_list = glob.iglob(os.path.join(base_path, "reports_*"))
for path in dir_list:
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        shutil.rmtree(path)
```